# Postfix bounce email when a recipient is not correctly written

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

I have an issue with a postfix install, version 3.5.17, in a email server with Debian 11, where when given an email with a list a recipients and if a recipient is not well written, like using uppercase letters or special characters like á or ñ, the email is bounced automatically for every recipient (even if it is in CC or BCC) in the list. I've checked the postfix configurations, in `main.cf`, but seems not to be a configuration related to this behavior. What are the posible causes of this behavior and how to correct it to only bounce for the wrong recipient but to deliver normally for the rest of addresses?

Comment: "bounced"? Please [quote relevant configuration, logs](https://serverfault.com/tags/postfix/info) and the specific status message (should look something like `5.5.2 Error: bad syntax`) you received in an [edit](https://serverfault.com/posts/1120099/edit).

Comment: Postfix can be configured to (not) validate domain names synchronously, but can only be configured to accept a few patterns malformatted commands from sending clients. Either way, I don't see how the behaviour you are describing is anything but preferable. Maybe the problem happens a few steps earlier, in the way you are processing PII, or some malfunction in the client software you use to pass mail to postfix. Whats the use case, whats the client?

Answer (score 0):

You can change this behavior by adding the following directive in your postfix, main.cf configuration.

```
strict_rfc821_envelopes = no
```